# How do I list all apps on Android 12?

Tags: android-12

This night my Pixel 3 updated to Android 12.

Now I can't find how to list all apps. In Android 11 and previous, I used to swipe from bottom to up but now that functionality seems to have disappeared.

It seems it's easier to search for one particular app if I know the exact name, but sometimes I don't know the exact name of the app so I want to see the full list of apps and select from there.

As a workaround, I can open the Play Store and open them from there, but that's tedious as I need to use so many taps.

How can I list all my installed apps easily on Android 12?

Comment: It works fine on Pixel 4a. You can also add the settings widget from app drawer to your home screen and choose app info instead of so many taps (via Play Store)//You can test with another launcher as an alternative if you don't like first method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [beeshyams](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/131553/beeshyams)' comment, I found out that the apps list is indeed present, but the movement to get it has slightly changed.

In Android 11 and before, I usually started swiping from the actual bottom from my phone (where my home button is) all the way up. But in Android 12, this only shows the list of running apps.

In order to get the full apps list, I need to start my swipe from anywhere *but* the home button.

Comment: Are you using 2-button navigation? There's a different behavior when swiping up on the home button for each navigation style.

Comment: @AndrewT. I don't know, I don't believe I've ever changed the default functionality since I own a phone from the Google lineup (first was Nexus S). How can I check that, to answer your question?

Comment: The navigation setting can be checked on Android Settings - System - Gestures - System navigation